# MySQL Error 1005

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

Right so code goes as such:

```
CREATE TABLE Seller (
sID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
sName CHAR (10), 
sAddress CHAR (30)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Sale (
sID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
iName CHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT sa_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (sID, iName),
CONSTRAINT sa_fk1
    FOREIGN KEY (sID)
    REFERENCES Seller (sID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT sa_fk2
    FOREIGN KEY (iName)
    REFERENCES Item (iName)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Item (
iPrice REAL,
iStock INT,
iName CHAR(10)
    PRIMARY KEY,
iDescription CHAR (30)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Copy (
oQuantity INT,
iName CHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT co_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (oQuantity, iName),
CONSTRAINT co_fk1
    FOREIGN KEY (oQuantity)
    REFERENCES Orders (oQuantity)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT co_fk2
    FOREIGN KEY (iName)
    REFERENCES Item (iName)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Orders (
oSeller CHAR (10),
oTypes CHAR (10),
oQuantity INT,
oPrice REAL,
oID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY
)ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Customer (
cID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
cName CHAR (10),
cAddress CHAR (30)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I've got drop commands at the beginning so every time i run this script they're removed oooor at least all of them except copy and sale. Whenever i try to drop them it fails as they're never created i keep getting the ERROR 1005 (HY000) crap followed by can't create table x.
Please help me sort this annoying pest of a problem. Tar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sale` table, you have

```
CONSTRAINT sa_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (iName) REFERENCES Item (iName)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

While, you are creating the `Item` table afterwards.

---

For creating the `Copy` table, you need an index on the `oQuantity` field in the `Order` table.

```
INDEX `oQty` (`oQuantity`)
```

Adding the above to Order table gets you to create the tables.

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69f4e).

Comment: admittedly that sorted the item however not copy :(

Comment: Similarly in your copy table, you are creating the `Orders` table afterwards.

Comment: I've rearranged the code so that copy comes last, still no dice :(

Comment: I have no idea how that works but I've been up too long. Cheers dudes, got to the point where i'm just staring at the screen hoping for it to change itself :)